# Adding a custom button to TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Have been trying to add a custom button for about 2 hours and I just can't get it to work. I don't know much about javascript maybe that's why. I did manage to get the button to show up and open a popup, but that's as far as I got.

I want the button to insert t he following into the HTML section of tinymce:

'

Here is my dialog.js file:

```
tinyMCEPopup.requireLangPack();

var InsertQuoteDialog = {
    init: function () {
        var s = tinyMCEPopup.editor.selection.getContent({ format: 'text' });
        if (s.trim().length > 0) {
            document.forms[0].blizzQuote.value = s.trim();
        }
    },

    insert: function () {
        var s1 = '<p class="blizzardQuote" ';
        s1 += Encoder.htmlEncode(document.forms[0].blizzQuote.value.trim()) + '</p>';

        tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, s1);
        tinyMCEPopup.close();
    }
};

String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
}

tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(InsertQuoteDialog.init, InsertQuoteDialog);
```

And my Dialog.htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>{#example_dlg.title}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="InsertQuoteDialog.insert();return false;" action="#">
    <p>Blizzard Quote</p>
    <p>Blizzard Quote: <input id="blizzQuote" name="blizzQuote" type="text" class="text" /></p>

    <div class="mceActionPanel">
    <div style="float: left">
        <input type="button" id="insert" name="insert" value="{#insert}" onclick="InsertQuoteDialog.insert();" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: right">
        <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="{#cancel}" onclick="tinyMCEPopup.close();" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically when I click on insert nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the javaScript console should show you that you are getting a JavaScript error on the dialog with the **Encoder** object not being known.

Simply include the JS file that defines **Encoder** on your dialog and it should all be good.

Comment: Please do *not* post your website URL in your answers. It makes your posts seem like spam.

Comment: Hi Andrew, The reason I've included it is to ensure disclosure that I work for a company that has a business relationship with MoxieCode.

Comment: You don't need a link to do that. An unrelated link makes your post spam. this post doesn't need any disclosure, anyway. Read the FAQ section on self promotion. It only says you need to disclose when you are posting links/info about your product/website.